# if isset statement - how to

Tags: php, session, isset

I need to run an if isset statement but i can't seem to get it right, please assist.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['schlid'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['schild'] as $index=>$child){ ?>
        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='schild[{$index}]' value='{$child}'/>";?>
    <?php } }?>
```

schild is stored in the session but it is not displaying the input fields from the foreach loop

Comment: i have schild in the session but it's not displaying the inputs

Comment: You realise that the variable names are different in your code as written? `$_SESSION['schlid'] != $_SESSION['schild']`.

Comment: What is the problem that you experience when trying to use that code? The isset function has been used correctly. The foreach statement though seems a bit off though in addition to the way you break up your PHP is not necessary. Can you give us some more insight into what specific problems you are experiencing?

Comment: @BOMEz the code without the isset statement works and displays the foreach loop of the stored session data, with the isset it does not display the data (input fields) at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Xavier: Change

```
if(isset($_SESSION['schlid'])) {
```

to

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['schild'])) {
```